# How to place a link to automatically send message in the email template of odoo

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-10

I'm working with project issue on odoo 10,
right now I'm trying to put link in my email template.
I put link to view ticket using this href

```
href="localhost/mail/view?model=project.issue&amp;res_id=${object.id}">
```

what I want to do is how to put link to reply message in oe_chatter
so when user get email, they can just click the link to reply automatic answer.

Answer (score 0):

Hendra Sirait
if you are looking to get the link to the current record, you can generate using the below code, and you can modify with your requirement

```
base_url = request.env['ir.config_parameter'].get_param('web.base.url')
base_url += '/web#id=%d&view_type=form&model=%s' % (self.id, self._name)
```

Using the `def send_email` method in this you can pass your link on the `message_body`.So end-user can have direct access to this.

Thanks